# Windows 8.1 print directly to printer

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, printing, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows 8.1 native app and the functionallity I am implementing requires a direct print to the printer, avoiding the default print flyout of metro apps.

[image]

However, **I don't see the way to achieve it**. I only want to tap a button and print a document directly, it must be a simple and quick operation for the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported from a general purpose Windows Store app. The Windows Runtime print API allows the app to provide the data to print, but the user is in control of the actual printing and which printer it goes to.

If your app is side-loaded rather than deployed through the store then it can use a Brokered Windows Runtime Component (BWRC) to call the desktop printing API to print without user input.

BWRC docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your replay Rob, that way is right but now....how can I do for print the data directly to the printer?

Comment: You cannot print directly to a printer from a Windows Store app. The user is in control.

Comment: but it is an side-loaded app and @Rob said that it is possible....
I would known the way to print raw data directly to a printer using BWRC.

Comment: Follow the linked docs and sample to get to the desktop side and do the printing from there. An end-to-end sample is too big for SO.